# remove side bars & how to set page layout to About Us page in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, cms

How to remove `side bars`(**about us page**) & how to set `page layout` like `1column,2column-left` to `about us` page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If about-us page is CMS page. Then goto Admin panel `CMS->pages->aboutus`

Then goto `design Tab` you can change the layout from the layout list.

If you want to remove the side bar

write the below code in **Layout Update XML**

```
<remove name="left"/>
<remove name="right"/>
```

cheers